# JavaFX image ghosting while moving quickly

Tags: java, image, swing, javafx-8

I stumbled upon a problem: if an image is moving at a high speed across the screen it is rendered incorrectly producing a ghosting effect. I think we can rule out my monitor being the problem as this type of movement was flawless in swing (with the same framerate).

Looks like: [image]

Code (merged from 3 classes):

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;


public class Constructor extends Application{

        Image player, shot;
        static Dimension screen = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        static int wid = screen.width;
        static int hei = screen.height;
        static boolean up, down, left, right, rotleft , rotright;
        static double x = (wid/2)-109;
        static double y = (hei/1.5)-132;
        static double velx = 0, vely = 0, velx2 = 0, vely2 = 0;
        static double forspeed = 0, sidespeed = 0;
        static int rotat = 0;

        public void load(){
                player = new Image("res/sprite.png");
        }

        @Override
        public void start(final Stage frame) throws Exception{

                load();

                frame.setTitle("DEFAULT");
                frame.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

                Group root = new Group();              
                final ImageView ship = new ImageView();
                ship.setImage(player); 
                root.getChildren().add(ship);

            frame.setScene(new Scene(root,  wid,  hei, Color.BLACK));

                frame.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
                        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.W)
                                   up = true;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.S)
                                   down = true;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.Q)
                                   left = true;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.E)
                                   right = true;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.A)
                                   rotleft = true;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.D)
                                   rotright = true;

                        }
                });
                frame.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
                        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE)
                          {
                              frame.close();
                                  System.exit(0);  
                          }
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.W)
                                   up = false;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.S)
                                   down = false;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.Q)
                                   left = false;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.E)
                                   right = false;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.A)
                                   rotleft = false;
                          if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.D)
                                   rotright = false;

                        }
                });
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                frame.setHeight(hei);
                frame.setWidth(wid);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setFullScreen(true);
                frame.show();

                 new AnimationTimer() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(long now) {

                        gameloop();
                        ship.setTranslateX(x);
                        ship.setTranslateY(y);
                        ship.setRotate(rotat);
                    }
                }.start();
        }

        public static void gameloop(){
        if(Shared.up)
                forspeed += 1;
        if(Shared.down)
                forspeed -= 1;
        if(Shared.right)
                sidespeed += 1;
        if(Shared.left)
                sidespeed -= 1;

        if(Shared.rotleft)
                rotat -=3;
        if(Shared.rotright)
                rotat +=3;

        velx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotat-90))*forspeed + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotat))*sidespeed;
        vely = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotat-90))*forspeed + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotat))*sidespeed;

        if(!Shared.up && !Shared.down)
        {
                if(forspeed > 0)
                        forspeed -= 0.2;
                else if (forspeed < 0)
                        forspeed += 0.2;
        }
        if(!Shared.right && !Shared.left)
        {
                if(sidespeed > 0)
                        sidespeed -= 0.2;
                else if (sidespeed < 0)
                        sidespeed += 0.2;
        }

        x += velx;
        y += vely;

        screencolisions();
        }

        private static void screencolisions() {
                // LEFT RIGHT
                if(x < 0)
            {
                x = 0;
                sidespeed = 0;
            }
            else if (x+218 > Shared.wid)
            {
                x = Shared.wid-218;
                sidespeed = 0;
            }

                // UP DOWN
            if(y < 0)
            {
                y = 0;
                forspeed = 0;
            }
            else if (y+164 > Shared.hei)
            {
                y = Shared.hei-164;
                forspeed = 0;
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to insert images properly.

Comment: Is it possibly some weird buffering issue?

Comment: Kamil, this was my first post and posting images is not allowed in the first few posts.

Comment: I recognize that design.  That's a Kilrathi Gothri class heavy space superiority fighter.  My nemesis in Privateer 1. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing is you are using AWT classes in Javafx .. They are not friends (most of the time).

Instead of using Dimension and the AWT toolkit,
Use the provided Javafx Screen class

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
wid = screen.getBounds().getWidth();
hei = screen.getBounds().getHeight();
// Visual bounds will be different depending on OS and native toolbars etc..
// think of it as desktop bounds vs whole screen
```

For example:

```
public class ScreenBounds extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        System.out.println("ScreenBounds : " + screen.getBounds() + "\nVisualBounds : " +   screen.getVisualBounds());
        Platform.exit();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

prints:

```
compile-single:
run-single:
ScreenBounds : Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1680.0, maxY=1050.0, width=1680.0, height=1050.0]
VisualBounds : Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=40.0, maxX=1680.0, maxY=1050.0, width=1680.0, height=1010.0]
```

As you can see no Syntax error as you described.. 
Though that error is probably due to your variables being Integers not Doubles like the method returns;

ScheduledService Timer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author jdub1581
 */
public class NanoTimer extends ScheduledService<Void> {

    private final long ONE_NANO = 1000000000L;
    private final double ONE_NANO_INV = 1f / 1000000000L;

    private long startTime, previousTime;
    private double frameRate, deltaTime;
    private final NanoThreadFactory tf = new NanoThreadFactory();

    public NanoTimer() {
        super();
        this.setPeriod(Duration.millis(16));// equivalent to 60 fps
        this.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(tf));
    }

    public double getTimeAsSeconds() {
        return getTime() * ONE_NANO_INV;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    }

    public long getOneSecondAsNano() {
        return ONE_NANO;
    }

    public double getFrameRate() {
        return frameRate;
    }

    public double getDeltaTime() {
        return deltaTime;
    }

    private void updateTimer() {
        deltaTime = (getTime() - previousTime) * (1.0f / ONE_NANO);
        frameRate = 1.0f / deltaTime;
        previousTime = getTime();

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        if (startTime <= 0) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        super.reset();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        previousTime = getTime();
    }
    private boolean init = true;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {                
                updateTimer();
                // perform NON UI calculations here

                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        super.succeeded();
        //update the UI here
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        getException().printStackTrace(System.err);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ElapsedTime: " + getTime() + "\nTime in seconds: " + getTimeAsSeconds()
            + "\nFrame Rate: " + getFrameRate()
            + "\nDeltaTime: " + getDeltaTime();
    }

    /*==========================================================================
        creates a daemon thread for use
    */
    private class NanoThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

        public NanoThreadFactory() {
        }

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r, "NanoTimerThread");
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }

    }
}//=============================================================================
```

Whatever class you put it in, just call the start method, probably best nested as a private class so variable can be used inside of it.. Or rewrite as you need..

I use it here: [My Cloth Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRsCcpbsdsg) and it works well doing 50k+ calculations per frame

Comment: What you are telling me is probably good to do, but is not related to the problem in any way. My use of that toolkit only returns 2 int values which I could input by hand for the same result. Also changing members to private does not affect graphical rendering in any way.

Comment: using any AWT from JavaFX will start whole AWT stack which can increase memory/proc consumption.

Comment: The game is running at steady 60fps. The code you posted gives a syntax error btw, perhaps you should check if stuff works before recommending it to people...

Comment: It does work, and with no errors in many custom windows I have..
I also don't recommend before I test.

Comment: Alright, you didnt mention that it reqires to be in the start void (which is not very usefull to me as I need it to be accessible by other classes). Anyway this is a useless answer, even without this or awt with hardcoded values the graphics obviously stay the same. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Trying to help ya out here... 
Have you tried setting the system arg "-Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=" true or false?
Also I've had strange stuff happen with animationTimer, maybe create  a timer out of a scheduled service instead? I do know that animation timer is scene pulse dependant..

Comment: Alright I gave the sysarg a shot, seems to have no effect, true or false. I don't really know anything about animation timers, I'm just trying to make a simple game in JavaFX and using that was the only way I found that worked. Is there anything better I could use?

Comment: I wasn't harping on you for the AWT stuff, but in general it is not good to include it in FX unless certain steps are made.. Which made me believe that AWT was blocking some things or slowing updates down.. So with the AnimationTimer, if a method takes longer than the "pulse" that fires the timer to update it's (long now) you will get some lag/updates not firing when they should... Which is also why I suggested a ScheduledService instead.. I will update my answer to include one implementation that I use. I know it's a pain but I really think you should remove all the AWT and see if the prob

Comment: continues.. 
If it does, then there is probably a bug that should be filed.. if Not then we know the source of the problem is AWT .. 
I don't remember the process for including AWT (though I remember something had to be done before FXThread started), but you can search for "JavaFX SysTray" and try those steps to activating and managing AWT as well .. The only other thing I can think of is to maybe put a small delay in your timers handle method(maybe updates to fast?) I'll get you my Service Timer though ,, look for code above..